# Child div overflows in parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div `box-container` that is a child in the `viewBlocks` div.

The problem I am having is that the `box-container` is overflowing out of `viewBlocks`. I have tried adding `position: relative` to `viewBlocks`, but that did nothing, and I couldn't find an answer with any other question on this site :/.

```css
.viewBlocks {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    height: 700px;
    width: 190px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: darkgray;
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
  
.box h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="viewBlocks">
    <!-- Class box -->
      <div id="box-container">
        <div class="box">
          <h2>Class</h2>
          <input class="class-name-form">
          <button class="class-name-btn" disabled>Set Class Name</button>
          <button disabled>Add Method</button>
          <button class="add-variable" disabled>Add instance variable</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Class Box -->
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `position: relative` is not enough. You have to define where the child should be placed within the parent.

By default, the child position will be `left: 0` and `top: 0`, which will make your box overflowed (since the child's width is 250px but the parent is just 190px).

Read below code for better explaination:

```css
.viewBlocks {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    height: 700px;
    width: 190px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: darkgray;
    /* Use this and the children will be positioned relatively within this element*/
    position: relative;
}
.box {
    /* Define the placement here*/
     right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    /* Change this to 100% if you want the element to fill its parent's width*/
    width: 100%; 
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
  
.box h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="viewBlocks">
    <!-- Class box -->
      <div id="box-container">
        <div class="box">
          <h2>Class</h2>
          <input class="class-name-form">
          <button class="class-name-btn" disabled>Set Class Name</button>
          <button disabled>Add Method</button>
          <button class="add-variable" disabled>Add instance variable</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Class Box -->
    
    </div>
```